# Why ExcelJs plugin is not working in IE11?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular9, exceljs

I am using Angular 9 and excelJs 4.1.1, this is working fine in chrome but only in IE11 giving Error: Invalid range in character set in polyfills-es5.js

When I remove the this dependency from package.json, everything working fine.

I have added all the polyfills suggested in https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs

Polyfills.ts

```
import 'core-js/modules/es.promise';
import 'core-js/modules/es.string.includes';
import 'core-js/modules/es.object.assign';
import 'core-js/modules/es.object.keys';
import 'core-js/modules/es.symbol';
import 'core-js/modules/es.symbol.async-iterator';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
import './unicode-regex-polyfill';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

unicode-regex-polyfill.ts

```
import rewritePattern from 'regexpu-core';
import { generateRegexpuOptions } from '@babel/helper-create-regexp-features-plugin/lib/util';

const { RegExp } = global;
try {
  new RegExp('a', 'u');
} catch (err) {
  // @ts-ignore
  global.RegExp = function(pattern, flags) {
    if (flags && flags.includes('u')) {
      return new RegExp(
        rewritePattern(
          pattern,
          flags,
          generateRegexpuOptions({ flags, pattern })
        )
      );
    }
    return new RegExp(pattern, flags);
  };
  // @ts-ignore
  global.RegExp.prototype = RegExp;
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@environments/*": ["src/environments/*"],
      "exceljs": [
        "node_modules/exceljs/dist/exceljs.min"
      ],
      // "@assets/images/*": ["src/assets/images*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/store": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.3",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jspdf": "1.4.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.6",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^3.0.0",
    "npm": "^6.14.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
    "exceljs": "^4.1.1",
  },
```

Kindly please help me to resolve this

**Everything working fine, if I remove the exceljs dependency from package.json**

Comment: https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/658

Comment: stop using ie 11 man  https://death-to-ie11.com/

Answer (score 1):

I have finally got it working in IE11 by doing below stpes

1. remove excelJS and file saver from package.json
2. add cdn paths to script tag in index.html
3. declare below variables as it is in ts files

   ```
   declare var ExcelJS: any ;
   declare var saveAs: any;
   ```
4. below code in same ts

   ```
    var workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('SheetName');

    workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then(function(buffer) {
      saveAs(new Blob([buffer], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), 
      'FileName.xlsx');
    });
   ```

ref : https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t900163/datagrid-the-latest-version-of-exceljs-doesn-t-work-in-ie11